# Having a closed and periodic curve $C$, in the unit sphere $\mathbb{S^2}$, calculate $\int_{C}\mathcal{K}_g(s)ds$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Let us have a closed and periodic curve $C$, in the unit sphere $\mathbb{S^2}$.(T understand better, visually the curve is like this: ~ , around the equator of the sphere). I have to calculate the geodesic curvature of $C$: $\int_{C}\mathcal{K}_g(s)ds$.

---

This is what I've done:

Let's define $\mathbb{S^2}=\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2 \cup C$ where $\Omega_1$ is the upper part of the sphere and $\Omega_2$ the lower part of the sphere. So $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are regular.

Using the global Gauss-Bonnet theorem, we know that:

$\int_C \mathcal{K}_g(s)ds+\iint_{\Omega_1}K dA=2\pi \mathcal{X}(\Omega_1)$

and

$-\int_C \mathcal{K}_g(s)ds+\iint_{\Omega_2}K dA=2\pi \mathcal{X}(\Omega_2)$

**Edit: On the one hand, as the curvature of the sphere is constant, I can get it out of the integral. On the other hand, the area of $\Omega_1$ and the area of $\Omega_2$ are equal. In addition, $\mathcal{X}(\Omega_1)=\mathcal{X}(\Omega_2)=1$ (because the surface is simple). So if I rest the second expression to the first one, I obtain $2\int_C \mathcal{K}_g(s)ds=0 \rightarrow \int_C \mathcal{K}_g(s)ds=0$.

**Edit2: I have correct some calculus mistakes.

Is this ok?

Comment: If your curve is the equator, then it is a geodesic and so, yes, its geodesic curvature is $0$. But you have to be careful with orientation of $C$ (as the boundary of one hemisphere, you go counterclockwise; as the boundary of the other, you go clockwise) — does the orientation affect $\int_C \kappa_g\,ds$? ... What if the curve is a different circle on the sphere?

Comment: the curve is AROUND the equator, what I wanted to say was that it is in the middle of the sphere, @TedShifrin

Comment: the curve is like this: ~~~~~~~~~ around the equator @TedShifrin

Comment: So put in the value for Gaussian curvature and forget about inequalities. You don’t need both hemispheres.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you explain me in another way, please? @TedShifrin

Comment: Is not what I've done okay? @TedShifrin

Comment: No. You didn't answer my question about what happens when you go on $C$ backwards. What happens to $\kappa_g$? ... Just use one equation, not both. You can explicitly say that everything else is.

Comment: I think I'm understanding what you are saying: If I take the first equation, I've got that $\mathcal{X}(\Omega_1)=1$ and $\iint_{\Omega_1}KdA=K\iint_{\Omega_1}dA=KArea(\Omega_1)$ and as $K=1/r^2$ and $A(\Omega_1)=A(\mathbb{S^2}/2)=\frac{4\pi r^2}{2}=2\pi r^2$, substituing, the value of the integral is $0$ @TedShifrin Is it ok? but I don't know what happens when you go on C backwards. That the orientation changes? for what did I need that?

Comment: Oh, when the orientation changes, you obtain the other omega, right? @TedShifrin

Comment: I'm asking you to explain where the negative sign came from in your second equation.

Comment: Ah okay, that minus is because $C$ is the border of $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ so the orientation is the opposite @TedShifrin But you've said that it is enough with the first equation, true?